# Im not able to perform action on read only elelments(Input field)either Click()or fillField() not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, codeceptjs

on read only input field elements im not able to perform any action  i have tried click()or fillfield()

Blockquote

Comment: Please post the code used to get the element using Selenium, as well as the relevant HTML code for the element you are targeting. Otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: One solution could be to manually emulate 'readonly' behaviour using Event.preventDefault() or another strategy (like placing a transparent element above the input to prevent user interaction and avoiding keyboard focus using 'tabindex').